# How to extract value after a particular string in scala (spark)?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I hava a dataframe with Column :

df =

```
itemType                   count
it_shampoo                  5
it_books                    5
it_mm                       5
{it_mm}                     5
it_books it_books           5
{=it_books} it_books        5
```

I need to get :

```
itemType                   count
it_shampoo                  5
it_books                    5
it_mm                       5
it_mm                       5
it_books                    5
it_books                    5
```

How do I extract replaces the  `it_books it_books`, `{=it_books} it_books` to `it_books`. Item Type will always follow `it_`

Answer (score 1):

Try regex, `^.*?(it_[\w]+).*$` to itemType and replace with first captured group `$1`.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/ANE8A7/1)

Comment: Your regex worked for me.  The code I used was
`val df2 = df.withColumn("itemType", regexp_extract($"itemType","""^.*?(it_[\w]+).*$""",1))`

Answer (score 0):

The below regex also works

```
scala> val df = Seq(("it_shampoo",5),
     | ("it_books",5),
     | ("it_mm",5),
     | ("{it_mm}",5),
     | ("it_books it_books",5),
     | ("{=it_books} it_books",5)).toDF("itemType","count")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [itemType: string, count: int]

scala> df.select( regexp_replace('itemtype,""".*\b(\S+)\b(.*)$""", "$1").as("replaced"),'count).show
+----------+-----+
|  replaced|count|
+----------+-----+
|it_shampoo|    5|
|  it_books|    5|
|     it_mm|    5|
|     it_mm|    5|
|  it_books|    5|
|  it_books|    5|
+----------+-----+


scala>
```